# Function and Floor Properties

Tags: proof-writing, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Call a function $f : x \mapsto \lfloor x / 2\rfloor$. Let $x_0 = n$, then $x_1 = \lfloor n / 2 \rfloor$ and $x_2 = \lfloor \lfloor n / 2 \rfloor \rfloor / 2 \rfloor$.... $x_k = f(x_{k-1}).$

How do we prove that $x_k = \left\lfloor \frac{n}{2^k} \right\rfloor$?

My best guess is induction but I'm not sure where to begin. I started off with using the floor definition but it got messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Induction is a good idea.

Note if $x_k = [\frac n{2^k}]$ then

$x_k \le \frac n{2^k} < x_k + 1$ so

$\frac {x_k}2 \le \frac n{2^{k+1}} < \frac {x_k}2 + \frac 12$

Now if $x_k$ is even than $\frac {x_k}2$ is an integer and

$\frac {x_k}2 \le \frac n{2^{k+1}} < \frac {x_k}2 + \frac 12<\frac {x_k}2+1$

And $x_{k+1} = [\frac {x_k}2] = \frac {x_k}2$ and $[\frac n{2^{k+1}}] = [\frac {x_k}2]=x_{k+1}$

And if $x_k$ is odd then $\frac {x_k}2 \pm \frac 12$ are integesr.

$\frac {x_k}2-\frac 12 <\frac {x_k}2 \le \frac n{2^{k+1}} < \frac {x_k}2 + \frac 12$

And both $x_{k+1} = [\frac {x_k}2] = \frac {x_k}2-\frac 12 $ and $[\frac n{2^{k+1}}] =\frac {x_k}2-\frac 12 =  [\frac {x_k}2] =x_{k+1}$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Consider $n$ expressed in binary, and for any natural number $m$, compare it to $\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2^m} \right\rfloor$ expressed in binary. Note the last $m$ binary digits are removed. Thus, after applying the $\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor$ operation $k$ times, you've removed the last $k$ binary digits, so it'll be the same as the result of $\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2^k} \right\rfloor$.

Comment: Is there a method using floor properties instead of looking at the binary representation?

Comment: @Zexion12 Note the general "floor properties" don't really give very much specific information regarding the results, especially when you repeatedly apply the floor operation. I don't know of any way to do this offhand. Note that considering the binary representation to me being the easiest & simplest way to deal with it since dividing by $k$ (for any integer $k$) repeatedly effectively removes the last digit in the $k$ base representation, with $k = 2$ in your case. Thus, any other method would, in some way, likely be similar to this anyway.